# Не переведена кнопка Expand snippet

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Не переведены кнопки Expand snippet

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот Return to post

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поправил. В ближайшее время, изменения будут на сайте. Если вы хотите самостоятельно вносить в перевод, пожалуйста, [вступите в ряды переводчиков–волонтеров](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032/)!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ну не :-) это ж что-то делать надо :-) :-) :-) а то - запостил картинку и все сделали :-)